# Suggestions for creating a multi-blog site in CakePHP with ACL 'memberships'

Tags: cakephp, membership, acl

I've been diving into CakePHP this year and I'm loving it!  However, I've just run across a problem that I'm not sure how to handle.  My database design is this--

**USER** can belong to one or more **WEBSITE**
A **WEBSITE** can have many **USER**

So I have a many-to-many relationship which is tracked in **MEMBERSHIP**

**MEMBERSHIP** also tracks what group_id the **USER** has for that **WEBSITE**.

For example, if user1 joins website3 as an administrator and website5 as a editor, then the **MEMBERSHIP** table has an entry reflecting both those roles.

Basically my problem is Cake's ACL. In the above-mentioned model, user1's group_id would change depending on which WEBSITE he's selected after logging in.  (And he could subsequently change to even more websites within the dashboard by changing the group_id again and again).  Cake's ACL appears to only handle 'user belongs to one group' period.

Can I trick the ACL by giving it the group_id from the session every time its changed and then reload the AROs? Would it make more sense to scrap ACL and create my own permissions module?

Any suggestions or ideas to point me in the right direction would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i think it will be the best way to create your own permission module.

the reasons are quite simple:

1. you can modify/extend it in any way YOU want
2. you will not break any cakePHP specifications